# Firebase Realtime Database Profiler $wildcard

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cli

I ran the database profiler recently for about 50 minutes, where about 200k operations were performed. I was most interested in bandwidth to keep an eye on costs. However, when stopping the profiler, I had difficulty understanding the bandwidth report. Here it is:

```
┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┬───────────┬────────┬─────────────────────┐
│ Path                                                     │ Total     │ Count  │ Average             │
├──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼───────────┼────────┼─────────────────────┤
│ /event/$wildcard/$wildcard/$wildcard                     │ 267.76 MB │ 49,171 │ 5.45 kB             │
├──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼───────────┼────────┼─────────────────────┤
│ /event/$wildcard/$wildcard                               │ 75.85 MB  │ 9,833  │ 7.71 kB             │
├──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼───────────┼────────┼─────────────────────┤
│ /event/$wildcard/$wildcard/$wildcard/$wildcard/$wildcard │ 1.50 MB   │ 45,513 │ 32.96106606903522 B │
├──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼───────────┼────────┼─────────────────────┤
│ /event/$wildcard/$wildcard/$wildcard/$wildcard           │ 1.38 MB   │ 14,133 │ 97.86648270006368 B │
├──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼───────────┼────────┼─────────────────────┤
│ /                                                        │ 529.45 kB │ 33     │ 16.04 kB            │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┴───────────┴────────┴─────────────────────┘
```

I understand this about the `$wildcard`:

> "Path: The path in your database where the operations occurred. If there are more than 25 child nodes, the profiler tool collapses these into a parent path and adds a $wildcard marker. You might see your database's root directory in the report, represented by a forward slash /."

Looking at the biggest bandwidth consumer, `/event/$wildcard/$wildcard/$wildcard` , I do not know what to make of it. Those wildcards could be anything. Is there a way to interpret it that I am missing?